# libvirt on amazon linux?

Tags: libvirt, amazon-ami

I'm trying to setup LXC on Amazon Linux based ec2-instance. Libvirt is missing on amzn1 if I install with "yum install libvirt". However to compile them seems non trivial work. but before that, have I missed anything?

Anyone can share the steps to install libvirt on Amazon Linux AMI?

Comment: Why use Amazon Linux? If you're seriously going to do LXC, I wouldn't consider a distribution that doesn't even include the tools!

Comment: Why not use a CentOS AMI instead?

Comment: Thanks for your good comments, later on I encountered other problem on installing the dependencies. though looks solvable but tiring. I chose Amazon AMI simply there's much optimisation for AWS done on it by Amazon (?) and we've been using it for some time, however I'll consider back to a Centos ami.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found reasonable answer, so here's some script for compiling and installing as I tested.

```
wget http://libvirt.org/sources/libvirt-1.1.4.tar.gz; 
tar zxvf libvirt-1.1.4.tar.gz;
sudo yum install -y libxml2-devel, device-mapper-devel, python-devel, libnl-devel;
cd libvirt-1.1.4;
./configure; make; sudo make install;
```